# Ubuntu is asking for sudo password on startup

Tags: password, startup, sh

Since some weeks ago, my Ubuntu 18.04 is asking for root password, saying *"sudo password needed to launch /bin/sh"*.

I skip this prompt but I wonder why this is happening and how can I diseble it?

It's a graphic prompt:

[image: capture]

Comment: How is it asking?

Comment: It's a graphic prompt, added capture

Answer (score 1):

Sudo isn't needed to launch `/bin/sh` so your permissions may have changed. Use this to check:

```sh
$ ll /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Aug  2  2018 /bin/sh -> dash*

$ ll /bin/dash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 154072 Feb 17  2016 /bin/dash*
```

Here `/bin/sh` is a link that all users have read/write/execute permissions to. The link points to `dash` so run `ll` on it as well to see that all users have read & execute permissions.

If your permissions are setup correctly, then there is something amiss with the program you are running on startup.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I didn't have access to this computer till now. The permissions are correct, the same that shown in your answer.