# How to find out which shell is asking for super user login?

Tags: bash, login

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.
Since a few weeks, whenever I start my PC, there is a window popping up and asking my password with this message :

```
It is neccessary to authenticate so that /bin/sh can be launched as super user.
```

*This might not be the exact english message, my interface is in french*

As this looked similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187250/ubuntu-is-asking-for-sudo-password-on-startup), I checked the permissions for `/bin/sh` and `/bin/dash`, everything seems fine, all users can read and execute.

So what is the best way to trace which program is launched at beginning and ask for this permission?

I have looked at `.bashrc` and `.profile` and nothing looks like something that would ask for permissions there.

Comment: It's probably not a shell *per se* - perhaps something you added to your `~/.config/autostart` startup applications?

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver. It seems you are right and there is  a dropbox entry in the `~/.config/autostart` directory which is responsible for it as I get the same window prompt asking for super user privilege when I launch manually the dropbox command which is in the autosart entry. Will try to dig a little more whether I can change that.